# EBS volume attached on running instance lambda logic required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have written a Lambda function which can be trigged only when an EBS volume is attached to running instance  and the status is completed. If this condition is true, then the below Lambda function will trigger and mounting the two EBS devices on my running OS.

Is this possible with a Lambda function or not? Please help me with the below code.  My two EBS volumes are created and attached with a CloudFormation template.

```
  from __future__ import print_function
    import boto3
    import os 
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')


    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        volume =(event['resources'][0].split('/')[1])
        if event['detail']['result'] == 'completed':
            attach=ec2.describe_volumes(VolumeIds=[volume])['Volumes'][0]['Attachments']
            if attach: 
                instance = attach[0]['InstanceId']
                if instance:
                    os.system('mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdg')
                    os.system('mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf')
                    os.system('mkdir -p /var/www/production /var/lib/SQL')
                    os.system('mount /dev/xvdf /var/www/production')
                    os.system('mount /dev/xvdg /var/lib/SQL')
                    os.system('echo  dev/xvdf /var/www/production ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2 >> /etc/fstab')
                    os.system('echo /dev/xvdg /var/lib/SQL ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2 >> /etc/fstab')         
                else:
                raise Exception('Volume ' + volume + ' not currently attached to an instance')
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing two concepts.  `os.system()` is going to execute these commands in the Lambda environment, which doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot  : then how to achive this any guidence

Answer (score 1):

Rohan,

Without some magic, Lambda cannot execute commands on EC2 instances.

I am assuming that you are creating new EC2 instances using CloudFormation and attaching the EBS volumes at that time.

You can put your OS level commands into the UserData under Resources in CloudFormation.

This link has examples:

[Deploying Applications on Amazon EC2 with AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html)

Comment: I am  not creating new instance i am attaching the EBS volumes on running instance this cfn script is ready but i am unable to format those volumes and  mounted to OS.

Comment: Kohan, I don't understand your reply. Did you move your commands from Lambda to the CloudFormat template?

Comment: Yes i have but still cannot mount EBS to existing volume Please download the code from here.                                               https://s3.amazonaws.com/sogetinl-mesos/EBS.json

Comment: no errors volume is attached to running instance but if you see my template i am unable to mount and format  the volumes which is shown in lsblk command  on running instance calling via cloudformation script.